# Compare two different size vectors of the same struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm developing a super-small package manager for custom purposes with a simple dependency checker, for that i need to compare two vectors (but same data type, an struct) the first vector has the installed packages by the user (using a simple SQLite query) , and the second vector the required packages to install.

The struct code is like:

```
typedef struct {
  std::string UniformTypeID;
  std::string PackageName;
  unsigned int Version; 
} PackageInfo;
```

i need to know how to compare these two vectors  but here's a problem, the size of the two vectors may vary, for example, if i use the size of the installed packages vector is smaller than the dependency packages (more larger), no find any package in their limit, but the requested package is more beyond of their limit.

I can use C++11.

Comment: And what do you expect to get as a result? A bool indicating whether they are equal? A vector of differences? A vector of identical elements? What?

Comment: You should define a criteria how two elements of the cectors will be compared. It is enough to define operator == for the structure or operator <.

Comment: @MariusBancila Ups sorry, an vector which has the missing dependencies, i mean the items can't found in the installed packages vector, i know was forgotting someting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) predicate for your `PackageInfo` class, either in terms of a binary predicate or simply provide an `operator<`.

With that you can sort your arrays (installed packages and required packages).  Then you can use the set manipulation functions of the `STL`:

```
std::vector<PackageInfo> installed_packages = ...;
std::vector<PackageInfo> required_packages = ...;
std::vector<PackageInfo> met_requirements;

std::sort(installed_packages.begin(), installed_packages.end());
std::sort(required_packages.begin(), required_packages.end());

std::set_intersection(
   installed_packages.begin(), installed_packages.end(),
   required_packages.begin(), installed_packages.end(),
   std::back_inserter(met_requirements));
```

`met_requirements` is now the set of `PackageInfo` that is present in both the `installed_pacakges` and `required_packages`.  You can then verify if all of the necessary `required_packages` are available.

Comment: There's also `set_difference` which might be what the questioner wants: I'm not sure from the question how the two vectors should be compared, but `set_difference` tells you the required packages that are not installed (or, if you prefer, the installed packages that are not required) as opposed to the required packages that *are* already installed.

Comment: I originally thought of `set_difference` however, I can envision a situation where there are `500` "installed" packages, and `3` "required" packages.  Then the difference can be any number between 497 and 500.  Though I admit, I am making some assumptions about the original question.

Comment: Indeed, it all depends what the questioner wants to do. If the idea is to download the required packages that are not installed, then compute the difference one way around. If the idea is to garbage-collect the installed packages that are not required then compute the difference the other way. If the idea is to list or version-check the already-met requirements then compute the intersection. You could even do all three in a suitable order :-)

Comment: Worked, Thanks you, i can take the rest myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cpplinq](http://cpplinq.codeplex.com/). Of course it does not make sense to use it from a single operation, but if you could use it for more things, then add the cpplinq.h header to your project and here is how you do it

```
std::vector<PackageInfo> installed_packages;
std::vector<PackageInfo> required_packages;

auto diff = from(installed_packages) 
         >> except(from(required_packages)) 
         >> to_vector();
```

Comment: Seems very interesting, i will give a try.